# Sharing a Google Maps: The library search is unknown

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to share the Google Maps by IFRAME and I've got this error in console

*The library search is unknown. Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries*

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2795.5423816131142!2d11.312607315808078!3d45.519289937786425!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x477f48c46ad35441%3A0x9a16514436b0fe8e!2sMarmi%20Zem%20di%20Ziche%20Enrico!5e0!3m2!1sit!2sit!4v1676708610573!5m2!1sit!2sit" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2795.5423816131142!2d11.312607315808078!3d45.519289937786425!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x477f48c46ad35441%3A0x9a16514436b0fe8e!2sMarmi%20Zem%20di%20Ziche%20Enrico!5e0!3m2!1sit!2sit!4v1676708610573!5m2!1sit!2sit" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
```

- I just copy and paste the above code
- I'm taking the code from Google Maps, -> Share -> Embed a Map
- I'm not using the API

do you know why?

Comment: The posted code works for me.

Comment: I can see that there was a bug filed during Feb 21, 2023 regarding this in the issue tracker. You guys can star it and +1 if you're affected by it to get updated. Here's the link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/270066866

Comment: @geocodezip The code works but you get an error in the console (press F12 in your browser).

Comment: It wasn't there before, now I see it.

Comment: Just an update to the issuetracker bug I linked above, it has now been marked as fixed and the fix for the issue will be included in the next version release.

Answer (score 0):

The W3C accessibility guidelines say iframes are not very user friendly to screen readers.

I also noticed a robust improvement of speed loading my website to use an image of the map as a link to the map opening the google map to it's usable form in a separate window.

Answer (score -3):

You are getting the mentioned console error because you must embed the iframe with a [Google Maps Platform **API key**].

Example:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Instead of:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2795.5423816131142!2d11.312607315808078!3d45.519289937786425!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x477f48c46ad35441%3A0x9a16514436b0fe8e!2sMarmi%20Zem%20di%20Ziche%20Enrico!5e0!3m2!1sit!2sit!4v1676708610573!5m2!1sit!2sit" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
```

The Google Maps Platform documentation is quite straightforward when it comes to the instructions to deploy this iframe. These are the two links you will need:

- How to embed a map: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/embedding-map?hl=es-419
- API usage: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-api-key

*Sidenote: Be wary that it is mandatory to provide a billing method when creating your key, so that Google can charge for the usage of the embeded map if it exceeds a given number of requests to their API.*

Comment: Hi, this is not true for embeds created by Google Maps in its own platform. This is however true for the Embed API.

Comment: I am already using an API key and I am getting the error message in the console anyway.